# How are the message boxes and runtime error windows localized in VB .NET?

Tags: vb.net, localization

I'm working with VB .NET application and trying to find a working way of localizing dialogue boxes (invoked by *InputBox* function - localize *Cancel* button) and any Runtime error notifications.

I tried

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture)
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture)
```

and it works on my local machine, however on the virtual machine used for the testing and set up more closely to how the real workstations would be it doesn't seem to work: there are still Cancel buttons and runtime errors in English (OS is localized in English).

I however can't seem to find any significant differences between my local machine and the virtual machine.

Could there be anything else that I'm missing?
Is the approach I'm using for localization here correct in the first place?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `InputBox` at all, under any circumstances. It's dodgy crap anyway. Create your own dialogue to work the specific way you want it to and then you can localise it like any other form.

Comment: @jmcilhinney well yes, but unfortunately I can't decide that because it's a big team project. In any case, the question of localizing Runtime Error alert notifications still stands.

Answer (score 0):

You can not localize system dialogs (MessageBox.Show). Its language is always in system's language. You can not localize Framework exception messages too - it is dependent on installed .NET Framework Language Packs.